# Using C# generics to create a mapper method with different return types

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a method to map int to string and string to int. I had the idea to do it in a single method, but not really sure if this is possible.

I got this far:

```
class MappingWithGenerics
    {
        [Test]
        public void IntToString()
        {
            string actual = Map<int, string>(1);
            Assert.AreEqual("1", actual);
        }

        [Test]
        public void StringToInt()
        {
            int actual = Map<string, int>("1");
            Assert.AreEqual(1, actual);
        }

        public TOut Map<Tin, TOut>(Tin element)
        {
            if(element.GetType() == typeof(int))
                return element.ToString();
            return Convert.ToInt32(element);
        }
    }
```

this gives compilation errors.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'TOut'
>
> Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'TOut'

Any idea how I could implement the Map method?

Comment: "this gives compilation errors" - *What* compilation errors? What's the error message? What line? Please don't let us try this out for you just to get the same information that you already have.

Comment: And with that said, `if(element.GetType() == typeof(int))` is probably a red flag. In general, you should use generics *exactly* where you want the *same* behaviour for all types, so distinguishing which type you are looking at seems contradictory.

Comment: your method signature says it's returning a `TOut` object, but you're trying to return a `string` or an `int`.  Your generics don't serve a purpose here.

Comment: Sorry about that, compilation errors are:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'TOut'

Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'TOut'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement the method like this:

```
    public TOut Map<Tin, TOut>(Tin element)
    {
        object outValue;
        if(element.GetType() == typeof(int))
            outValue = element.ToString();
        else
            outValue = Convert.ToInt32(element);
        return (TOut)outValue;
    }
```

But I really wonder why do you need such a method. I'm sure there is better way to solve your broader problem.

Comment: What I want to achieve it's a bit more complicated than the actual example. It's a more a mapping between classes, but it didn't want to ask the question with a complicated example.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 5):

Generics are for when you want the same functionality across a bunch of different types. In this case, you're dealing with two specific types and you want different functionality between them. Generics aren't really what you want, especially when you can do the same thing with simple method overloading:

```
class MappingWithoutGenerics
{
    public string Map(int x)
    {
        return x.ToString();
    }

    public int Map(string s)
    {
        return Convert.ToInt32(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: That would work for this two cases, but it's not really what I want.
What if want to map from int to bool? Map<int, bool>(1)

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code does not compile is that you coded a *generic* method with only two specific types in mind. You can shoehorn this into a generic function with conversion to `object`, but this is not a good idea.

You can implement the desired functionality using the `Convert` class, like this:

```
public static TOut Map<Tin, TOut>(Tin element) {
    return (TOut)Convert.ChangeType(element, typeof(TOut));
}
```

Your test methods will work without a change. However, the method will be capable of conversions beyond `string`->`int` and `int`->`string`: you will be able to convert between any pair of types supported by [`Convert.ChangeType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/NtklX6)